# Can you repeatedly use Fortune Hex twice a day if you have the Accursed Hex feat?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, witch

Can you repeatedly target yourself or a party member twice a day with the Fortune Hex if you take Accursed Hex as a feat?

> **Fortune (Su):** The witch can grant a creature within 30 feet a bit of good luck for 1 round. The target can call upon this good luck once per round, allowing him to reroll any ability check, attack roll, saving throw, or skill check, taking the better result. He must decide to use this ability before the first roll is made. At 8th level and 16th level, the duration of this hex is extended by 1 round. Once a creature has benefited from the fortune hex, it cannot benefit from it again for 24 hours.

> #### Accursed Hex
>
> You can make a second attempt at failed hexes.
>
> **Prerequisite:** Hex class feature.
>   **Benefit:** When you target a creature with a hex that cannot target the same creature more than once per day, and that creature succeeds at its saving throw against the hex's effect, you can target the creature with the same hex a second time before the end of your next turn. If the second attempt fails, you can make no further attempts to target that creature with the same hex for 1 day.
>   **Normal:** You can only target a creature with these hexes once per day.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can't

Accursed Hex has 2 requirements:

- Target a creature with a hex that can only affect a target once per day (satisfied)
- That creature succeeds at its saving throw (not satisfied)

As described in its description (and backed up in its details), Accursed Hex is for re-trying failed hostile hexes. Since Fortune doesn't allow a saving throw, it is ineligible for Accursed Hex to retry it.

Additionally: RAW you CAN still target the same creature with Fortune, that creature just can't benefit from it.

Comment: The hostile hexes don't mention saving throws either.

Comment: Hex: Witches learn a number of magic tricks, called hexes, that grant them powers or weaken foes. At 1st level, a witch gains one hex of her choice. She gains an additional hex at 2nd level and for every 2 levels attained after 2nd level, as noted on Table 2–10. A witch cannot select an individual hex more than once.

Unless otherwise noted, using a hex is a standard action that does not provoke an attack of opportunity. The save to resist a hex is equal to 10 + 1/2 the witch's level + the witch's Intelligence modifier.

Comment: Misfortune (Su): The witch can cause a creature within 30 feet to suffer grave misfortune for 1 round. Anytime the creature makes an ability check, attack roll, saving throw, or skill check, it must roll twice and take the worse result. A Will save negates this hex. At 8th level and 16th level, the duration of this hex is extended by 1 round. This hex affects all rolls the target must make while it lasts. Whether or not the save is successful, a creature cannot be the target of this hex again for 1 day.

Comment: nevermind, i lied

Comment: Technically your ally could choose to make a saving throw vs your Fortune, and if he succeeds you can use Accursed Hex to cast it again. However the reasons why you and your ally would do that are very mysterious.

Comment: @AnneAunyme Ambiguous. Fortune doesn't say anything about a save or failure, and you can't just decide to make a saving throw against things that don't allow them ("I save against your magic missile""How""With my d20!"). However, as FrancisJohn linked, there are rules for resisting ALL hexes, which Fortune is one (even though it's a beneficial one).